# Random values popping up on typecasting to datatype

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, type-conversion, typecasting-operator

```
template <class T>
    BOOST_FORCEINLINE bool Decoder::readDecimal(const char* data_ptr, T& input, int &offset, int &size)
    {
        log_.writeln("readDecimal : ", std::string(data_ptr + offset, data_ptr + offset + 10));
        if(offset >= size)
            return false;
        T temp = 0;
        bool decimal = false;
        int mul = 1;
        assert(data_ptr[offset] != '\x01' && data_ptr[offset] != '=');
        for(int i = offset; i < size; i++)
        {
            log_.writeln("readDecimal : ", temp);
            if(data_ptr[i] == '\x01' || data_ptr[i] == '=')
            {
                log_.writeln("readDecimal : ", temp);
                input = temp;
                offset = i + 1;
                return true;
            }
            else if(data_ptr[i] == '.')
            {
                decimal = true;
                continue;
             }
             if(!decimal)
                temp = temp*10 + int(data_ptr[i] - '0');
             else
             {
                log_.writeln("readDecimal : ", temp, " ", int(data_ptr[i] - '0'), " ", T(int(data_ptr[i] - '0')), " ", pow(10,mul), " ", (T(int(data_ptr[i] - '0'))/pow(10,mul)));
                temp = temp + T(int(data_ptr[i] - '0'))/pow(10,mul);
                 mul++;
             }
        }
        return false;
     }
```

I am using the above function is convert a formatted string to decimal datatypes(float/double), but for some reason, I am seeing some random values popping up at the end of the decimal places.

Basic Input Output:

```
Input : "19.6"
Output : 19.60000038 (float)
```

The output log:

```
readDecimal : 0.65^A64=20
readDecimal : 0
readDecimal : 0
readDecimal : 0
readDecimal : 0 6 6 10 0.6
readDecimal : 0.6000000238
readDecimal : 0.6000000238 5 5 100 0.05
readDecimal : 0.6500000358
readDecimal : 0.6500000358
```

Another example :

```
readDecimal : 19.6^A64=20
readDecimal : 0
readDecimal : 1
readDecimal : 19
readDecimal : 19
readDecimal : 19 6 6 10 0.6
readDecimal : 19.60000038
readDecimal : 19.60000038
```

Function call:

```
decoder.readDecimal<float>(data_ptr, MDIncGrp[index].MDEntryPx, offset, data_size);
```

Comment: `data_ptr + offset + 10` - How do you know that it's always safe to read 10 bytes?  Shouldn't you be using `size`?

Comment: That just logging, I just wanted to see the actual string, and the decimal number is usually less than 10 bytes. @0x5453

Comment: Keep in mind that if those log statements end up invoking Undefined Behavior, you can no longer trust any output from this program.

Comment: With floats only 7 digits (wherever the decimal part is) are trusted. With doubles, 15 digits. Rest of digits you plot are undefined.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @Ripi2 I have added another example with less than 7 numbers after decimals being unexpected.

Comment: `19.60000` Total 7 digits. The rest is whatever.

Comment: Are you talking about `238`?  Please be **specific**.  To my eye (and many people reasonably fluent in IEEE floating point numbers), `238` is and similar is completely expected, while `5 5 100 0.05` is a bunch of random nonsense.  Looking at your output, "random values poping up" would refer to `5 5 100 0.05` naively.  Meanwhile, I suspect you are confused by `238`.  Include sample **input**, exact **output** from that sample input, and **what you expect the output to be** from that sample input.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Thanks for the feedback, as I shared the logging code and the logs I didn't include it, just edited the basic input-output in. Do let me know if you know what's causing this?

Comment: @Ripi2 what can be a solution to this? even when I do `temp = (int)(temp * 10000);
 temp = (float)temp / 10000.0;` I get the same number

Comment: @DEEPANSHNAGARIA: A solution to what?  This surely isn’t correctly rounded, but at a basic level there’s no evidence here that anything is **wrong**.

Comment: @DavisHerring `log_.writeln("readDecimal : ", temp, " ", mul, " ", (temp/mul));` productes an output of : `readDecimal : 196 10 19.60000038` I am unable to figure out what's causing the extra `38` to appear and want to get rid of it.

Comment: The (32-bit) `float` nearest 19.6 **is** 19.6000003814697265625 exactly.  If you want to round it, do so, but you may have to make a string yourself if your logging utility doesn't expose that control.

Comment: @DavisHerring can you help me with what you mean by round? Actually, I need the actual 19.6 out of it as double/float and if I do something like `(int) (temp*100)` and then dividing, it gives me the same thing

Comment: @DEEPANSHNAGARIA: You don’t seem to be realizing that you have the correct **value** (*i.e.*, “19.6”) already; this is a matter of displaying it according to user preferences/aesthetics, and that may depend on your logging system (although you can always use `std::snprintf`).

Comment: If you read the link I posted above (seems broken, this one works: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) you'll discover that a float value **may or may not have** an exact representation. That's the price to pay for using IEEE eficent format.